# Integrating $\iint_{A}x^2+4y^2\ dx\, dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I have:

$$\iint_A x^2+4y^2\ dx \,dy$$

where $A$ is $y=x^2$ and $x=y^2$ is the enclosed enclosure.

someone can help me to raise the integral.

Comment: Do you know Green's theorem? $(x^2 + 4y^2)dxdy = d(- \frac{4y^3}{3}dx + \frac{x^3}{3}dy)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You should make a sketch to get a good idea of the region $A$, bounded between the graphs of the parabolas $y=x^2$ and $x=y^2$.

Note that they intersect in $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ and that for $0 \le x \le 1$, you have $x^2 \le \sqrt{x}$. Does that help to set up the boundaries for $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hin**t: Draw the region first. Thus $\int \int_A (x^2+4y^2)dxdy= \int_{0}^1 \int_{x^2}^{\sqrt{x}} (x^2+4y^2)dydx$ . Can you continue?

Comment: i will try thanks